# Pingdom Website Speed Test: Connect time is too long

Tags: performance, windows-server-2008, asp.net, performance-monitor, performance-tuning

My e-commerce website was performing poor and I decided to find out the cause.
A real good application came in help for me [Pingdom Website Speed Test](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/).When I analysed website with this, report was some thing like this:

[image]

As you can see that **the connect time of website is taking almost 75% of total load-time**. But what I can't understand is what does this connect time mean and what do I need to do to reduce this. Or is it common to have this much connect time?

Comment: What are the effective values (not only in percent) - if all of it is about 2ms it is not worth looking into it. Which site?

Comment: @FiveO total load time of site is 3 sec and 2.25 sec is only for connect

Comment: ok that's quite slow. What server do you use - or which hosting provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well just found [this post explaining the different states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753993/explanation-of-pingdom-results).

> the blue part is the time it takes to retrieve the content from the webserver

This means it is not the "connect" to the webserver, it is the time it takes to download the content.

So if your page has many elements (i.e. images), the performance of the webserver will influence the download speed of the images. Often the last images on your page will take longer (a long "download" time), even if the size is smaller than others.

Well I must say, the "analysis" of the pingdomtools is not optimal and leads (like in your case) to wrong interpretations. To proove it, maybe verify with another website analyzer.